# Parametrization of line segment

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Could anyone show me the standard parametrisation procedures of the line segments from

1) 1 to $1+i$

2) $1+i$ to $i$

3) Evaluate contour integral $\int_C x dz$ where $C$ is the union of the above segments.

Also, the parametrisation is not unique, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you with the first parametrization:

$1)$ $z(t)=(1-t)1+t(1+i)=1-t+t+ti=1+ti$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: $z(t)=(1-t)(1+i)+ti=1+i-t-ti+ti=1-t+i$. But the solution shows $2-t+i$, which I do not get.

Comment: the solution is certainly wrong :)

Comment: It all depends on the interval in which $t$ lies: if $t\in [1,2]$, the solution is correct. Note than parametrization of a curve is not unique.

Comment: The solution did indicate t is in $[1,2]$, but u do not see how could $t$ lie in this range. I mean, pictirially it should always lie between 0 and 1.

Comment: thank you @Kuifje for your remark! you are absolutely right

Comment: as for your comment, @math101: note that a path is simply a function $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. The domain is not necessarily $[0,1]$. It can always be reparametrized so that this happens, though

Comment: Ok. So both the answer I gave and the solution are correct. Depending which range of t chosen, right?

Comment: Yes! That's the point